# Mouseover to pause image slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I have an image slideshow that works, but I need to make it so that when you slide over with your mouse, the slideshow stops at the particular image and then when you release, starts the slideshow again.. Here is my function:

```
$(function(){
$(this).mouseover(function(){
    $(this).toggle();
});
$('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
setInterval(function(){
  $('.fadein1 :first-child').fadeOut()
     .next('img').fadeIn()
     .end().appendTo('.fadein1');}, 
  3000);
  });
```

Could someone please help? It's really annoying me now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your slideshow function to keep better track of the images, something like this should work :

```
$(function(){
    var timer, elm=0, images = $('img', '.fadein1');
    images.not(':first').hide().end().on({
         mouseenter: function() {
             clearInterval(timer);
         },
         mouseleave: function() {
             timer = setInterval(slider, 3000);
         }
   });

   timer = setInterval(slider, 3000);

   function slider() {
     var image = images.eq(elm);
     image.fadeOut();
     elm = elm!=images.length-1 ? image.next('img').index() : 0;
     images.eq(elm).fadeIn();
   }
 });​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/KSRaN/)

Answer (score 0):

try this ...

```
var interval;

function slide(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein1 :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein1');}, 
      3000);
  });

  $(function(){

    $('.fadein1').hover(function(){
        clearInterval(interval);
    },function(){
      slide();
    });

    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    slide();

  }
```

Comment: Where did you call the `slide()` function to start it when the dom is ready ?

Comment: Hey, I tried this.. It didn't work, any other suggestion? Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You normally just set a semaphore to say "hey, i'm paused" when you want to do so. Then, in your setInterval function, you say if(paused) {return;} and only continue if not paused.

Comment: Hey so something like this: $(function(){
 var stopped = false;
 $('.).mouseover(function(){
  stopped = true;
 });
 if(!stopped)
 {
     $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
      setInterval(function(){
        $('.fadein1 :first-child').fadeOut()
          .next('img').fadeIn()
          .end().appendTo('.fadein1');}, 
       3000);
   }else{
     return 0;
   }
});

Comment: Something - but you may want to set stopped to false when the cursor leaves the element. [$.hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) is your friend!